# Proving that a local martingale given by a stochastic integral is not a martingale

Tags: probability-theory, brownian-motion, martingales

Let $X_t=\int_0^t e^{W_s^2}dW_s$ for $0\leq t\leq 1$ and show that is not a martingale.

I guess the reason is that the expectation is not finite,
but I'm not sure how to show it precisely. In fact $Ee^{2W_s^2}=(1-4s)^{-1/2}$ for $0<t<1/4$ and infinity otherwise, but I don't think I can use Ito's isometry directly since this expectation is not finite. If I could that would give me $E X_t=\int_0^t Ee^{2W_s^2} ds=\infty$ for $t>1/4$.

So here is what I tried:

As in the construction of the integral, let 
$$t_n=\inf \left\{ t\, |\, \int_0^te^{2W_s^2}ds \geq n  \right\} \wedge t$$ which is a sequence of stopping times increasingly converging to $t$.
Now we can use Ito' s isometry and write 
$$E (  \int_0^{t_n} e^{W_s^2}dW_s)=\int_0^{t} E(e^{2W_s^2}1_{s\leq t_n}) ds.$$
 but I don't know how to compute 
$E\left(e^{2W_s^2}1_{s\leq t_n}\right)$ because I would need to know the joint distibution first..
Thank you

Comment: Note that Itô's isometry gives (at best) $X_t \notin L^2$ - but you want to prove $X_t \notin L^1$.

Comment: You are right, what I did was actually for $E X_t^2$. But then how to proceed to show it's not in $L^1$?

Comment: Sorry but Itô's isometry does **not** yield
$$E \left(  \int_0^{t_n} e^{W_s^2}dW_s\right)=\int_0^{t} E(e^{2W_s^2}1_{s\leq t_n}) ds.$$

Comment: Yes, I should have put a square. I was computing EX_t^2 and forgot to type it